# RMySQL resultset is not "complete" after all results have been fetched

Tags: r, rmysql

In a script that processes a lot of rows in a MySQL server, I use `dbSendQuery` and `fetch` to throttle the fetching and processing of results.

When my `fetch` command retrieves exactly the number of rows available (or left) in the resultset, leaving 0 rows to be fetched, `dbHasCompleted` returns `FALSE` whereas I expected it to return `TRUE`.

```
query <- "select record_id, name 
          from big_table left join another_table using (record_id) 
          limit 500"

resultset <- dbSendQuery(con, query)   # con: DB connection

while(!dbHasCompleted(resultset)) {
  input <- fetch(resultset, n = 500)
  print(paste("Rows fetched:", nrow(input)))
  # process input ...
}
```

I expected this loop to run once, but there is an extra run as after processing, `print` is called again:

```
Rows fetched: 500
...
Rows fetched: 0
```

Apparently, `dbHasCompleted(resultset)` is false when the exact number of available rows is fetched (same behaviour is observed for n = 1000, 2000, 3000). When in this script n = 501, there is no second loop.

Is this to be expected? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I get the same error. Appears to be a bug, don't think you are doing anything wrong.